# Elasticsearch Docker Authentication Exception with Python client

Tags: python, docker, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch Docker Version: 8.5.0
Python Version: 3.10
elastic-transport==8.4.0
elasticsearch==8.7.0

Elastic Search Docker Run command:
`docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -e "discovery.type=single-node" -e "xpack.security.enabled=true" -e "ELASTIC_PASSWORD=my_pass" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.5.0`

Python connection code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers


es = Elasticsearch(
    ['http://localhost:9200'],
    basic_auth=('elastic', 'my_pass')
)
print(es.ping())
print(es.info())
```

I'm always getting:

`elasticsearch.AuthenticationException: AuthenticationException(401, 'security_exception', 'unable to authenticate user [elastic] for REST request [/]')`

Changing password, or also setting the user per ENV Variable in the docker run, makes no difference, tried all variations. Always the same error. Elastic Logs are nowhere to be found, and default logs do not help. What might be the issue?

Comment: [I can't reproduce your issue](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/7c5f30b86c0527bf1be3de90fb3ca060)

Comment: Wth....Now it works, I don't know, everything was literally the same. It could have been the public wifi on the train I was using, but that makes no sense at all. Guess it needed a second person to try it, thank you!